# HTML Input Form to a Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm trying to implement an HTML form input, of which will take the numerical value and convert it into a variable in Javascript. This will then be used with chartjs to plot an graph.

I have the graph fully functioning if I input the variable separately, as used in the code below. I have been trying to use a function to take the value from the HTML form.

```js
var force = 10
var numberOfPointLoads = 1
var pointLoadLocation = 5
var beamLength = 10
var supportCondition = "simplySupported"
var split = beamLength //No. of Finite Elements


var splitArrayYAxis = Array.from({
  length: (split + 1)
}, (x, i) => i);
var yAxis = splitArrayYAxis.map(x => (x * (beamLength / split)));
yAxis.push(pointLoadLocation)
yAxis.push(pointLoadLocation)
yAxis.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
});

var splitArrayXAxis = Array.from({
  length: (split + 1)
}, (x, i) => i);
var xAxisEnd = splitArrayYAxis.map(x => (x * (beamLength / split)));
xAxisEnd.push(pointLoadLocation)
xAxisEnd.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
});

var xAxisStart = xAxisEnd.splice(0, (xAxisEnd.indexOf(pointLoadLocation) + 1));
xAxisEnd.unshift(pointLoadLocation);

var shearForce = force / 2

var xAxisStart = xAxisStart.map(x => (shearForce))
var xAxisEnd = xAxisEnd.map(x => (-shearForce))
var xAxis = xAxisStart.concat(xAxisEnd)

var data = yAxis.map((v, i) => ({
  x: v,
  y: xAxis[i]
}));


//chart is below this

new Chart(document.getElementById("shearPointLoad"), {
  type: "scatter",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "MyScatter",
      lineTension: 0,
      data: data
    }]
  },
  options: {
    stacked: false,
    bezierCurve: false,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Plot of the Scatter'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="shearPointLoad" width="400" height="250"></canvas> Force Input <input type="text" id="userInput"></input>
<button id="submitter">Submit</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

The variable will be equal to the value of the HTML and will be reassigned when updated.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT

```js
let someInput = document.getElementById('someInput')

function onButtonClick() {
  let someVariable = parseFloat(someInput.value);
  console.info(someVariable);
}

var force = "someVariable"
var numberOfPointLoads = 1
var pointLoadLocation = 5
var beamLength = 10
var supportCondition = "simplySupported"
var split = beamLength //No. of Finite Elements
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="shearPointLoad" width="400" height="250"></canvas>

<input id="someInput" type="number" <input/>
<button onclick="onButtonClick()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `onclick` event to the button and define a function `plotchart()`:

```
<button id="submitter" onclick="plotchart()">Submit</button>
```

Now, to read the input value in the function:

```
var data = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
```

Now, wrap all you chart plotting code inside `plotchart()` function.

Comment: Hi Fiveelements, thanks so much, I took your code and it was pretty much spot on. Only thing that was missing was the .value at the end of the var data line.

Comment: Thanks. Modified to include `.value`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the button event `onclick`, so every time you click it, you can then grab the input's value using a reference to the element. Like the following snippet:

```js
let someInput = document.getElementById('someInput')

function onButtonClick() {
    let someVariable = parseFloat(someInput.value);
    console.info(someVariable);
}
```

```html
<input id="someInput" type="number" />
<button onclick="onButtonClick()">Click me</button>
```

After this, you may use `someVariable` for anything you need.

Notes:

- Use a `type="number"` input for better UX (so users can't input text or some other characters)
- Consider resetting the input value after clicking the button.

Comment: Hi Francisco, thanks for the quick reply, I'm still not quite getting the desired effect from it, I'm trying to use .. var force = someVariable although it is not plotting. Updated the original question to show the change.

Comment: You should append the `someVariable` to the data array of the chart. Then, update the chart.